# How to use a content observer in android

Tags: android, listview, cursor, contentobserver

I have a function in my app that returns a cursor.  The cursor can potentially return many rows of data, and always returns 5 columns of data from two joined tables.  Columns 1-4 never change.  Column 5 can change based on user actions. How do I register a content observer to notify me when that 5th column changes from any row changes.  Here is an example.  In my main Activity, I call

```
Cursor cursor = db.getNotifiedCursor();
```

This gives me my 5 columns of data.  Then I take those 5 columns of data and use a cursor adapter to put each row as a list item in a ListView.

When the user has not clicked on a list item, the background for that item is one color.  After they click on the list item, it is another color.  This is simply to help them differentiate between items they have already viewed, and not viewed.

The 5th column can be null, zero (0) or one (1).  If it is null then it isn't in my ListView.  If it is a zero it is in my list view with the first background color.  If it is a 1, then it is in my listview with the second background color.

My original way of solving this problem was to use a Handler that infinitely loops every 750 milliseconds that re-loads the data from the list view with the correct colors.  I would prefer to only call that handler when the data changes because the loop version seems like a little hackish.